# Connection to Access database via Web API works fine when Web API is called locally, but exception on remote calls

Tags: c#, json, api, ms-access, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API server up and running. It can be accessed both locally and remotely and properly returns JSON representing a list of objects.

When I add the additional step of the Web API connecting to a local database (that is, the database on the same machine as the Web API) and returning results, it runs fine locally. However, when this code executes remotely (the Web API is called from a non-local machine; the database and Web API still reside on the same server), the Web API server returns an empty JSON string ("[]").

The following error is returned: The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine (server). The problem with this is I cannot install the Data Connectivity components to fix the problems on an iOS device...

What would the Microsoft Access database be doing that would cause this issue?

Comment: I question your assumption that the fault lies with the Microsoft Access database.

Comment: What would be the difference between calling the Web API locally vs. remotely? The code isn't different or anything. Also, the Web API returns sample data just fine remotely. It's the Access component that introduces the problem.

Comment: I added an exception error.

Comment: Sounds like a permission issue. When run locally, it is probably using your credentials to access the database, but when run remotely, it is stuck as the web service, which probably does not have the necessary access (ie, file permissions on file system or account permissions in Access db).

Comment: I am commenting rather than answering because I am not familiar with Web API.  But I would make two recommendations: first, because (as you note) you cannot install ACE.OLEDB on the client, you need to figure out why your code requires ACE.OLEDB on the client.  Then change the design of your application so that requirement  no longer exists.  Second, if you post a sample of your code, you might get some help identifying the problem.

Comment: Have you checked if the local user (IIS use) has access to the foldar that contains the Access database?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have installed the [Data Connectivity Components](http://blog.danbrust.net/2013/10/10/installing-microsoft-office-data-connectivity-components/) **and** have installed Microsoft Access with a valid key.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue, we assuming that server contains exactly the same instances we using locally, as @Pierceboggan stated, you need to install all the components related to Microsoft Access, when creating  the package, add related references.